# External Accessory with wifi

Tags: ios, xcode, wifi, external-accessory

I want to create an app which connects to an external device via wifi signal. I am connected with the wifi to the external device when I start the app.

In my app, i call:

```
NSArray *accessories = [[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] connectedAccessories];
```

but accessories remains empty.

What am I missing here?

(I created a simple app for which I followed the description from the Developer Library, but still no EAAccessory is found.)
Also, I tried EADemo but this also does not work.

Comment: What kind of accessory do you want to connect to?

Comment: EAAccessory is only for devices & accessories that connect to the port of an iPad or iPod nd also refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300711/how-to-know-when-ios-device-is-plugged-in

Comment: It's an ELM327 device for OBD2 information (car information). So I know the protocol's it uses, but don't know how to call a protocol. I thought EAAccessory could be used for this...

Comment: Technically EA can be used over Bluetooth, too. It's not too common though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, like iPatel says, EAAccessory is only for devices & accessories that connect to the port of an iPad or iPod.

But since you were saying that you are already connected via WiFi to the external device, it sounds like all you need to do is figure out an interface through which you can talk to this device.  Can you connect to the device through HTTP or some high level protocol, or can you use TCP or UDP to talk to it?

If you can, then that's all you need to finish getting your app connected to your external WiFi connected device.

Comment: Hmmm.. that's not mentioned anywhere... Nice... And how can I call a protocol? Because I know which protocol's the device has.