# Detect when iPhone is being unplugged and plugged in

Tags: swift

I am just trying to write simple code that detects when the iPhone is unplugged and then plugged in. But being event-driven, instead of using a while loop. This code does work, but doesn't detect if the phone is unplugged and will not update the printed text.

**EDIT**
In the long run I just want the phone to play a sound whenever the iPhone is unplugged. (Sorry for leaving the end goal out.). I was using this print statements just so I can make sure it was working.

```
func startCharger()
    {

        printscreen.text="Started charger protocol"

       UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled=true

        if(UIDevice.current.batteryState == .unplugged)
        {
            printscreen.text="Battery is unplugged"
        }
        else
        {
            printscreen.text="Battery is plugged in"
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to use notificationCenter I believe. https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotificationcenter

Comment: I saw that too, okay so I would I code that? I just started with swift today lol.. So I don't understand the syntax fully yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know when iOS device is plugged in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300711/how-to-know-when-ios-device-is-plugged-in).  Use KVO.

Comment: @JAL Why not notifications? It's cleaner.

Comment: @Sulthan on `EAAccessoryManager`?  Didn't see that answer when I flagged.  Might be best.

Answer (score 1):

Quick implementation of Dule' code.
Check if the power is connected. 
Copy these functions into your class.
Call isPowerConnected() in the viewDidLoad

```
func isPowerConnected(){
    UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(batteryStateChanged),
        name: .UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChange,
        object: nil)
}

var chargingVar = "" //Empty Variable

func batteryStateChanged(){
    if (UIDevice.current.batteryState == .charging) {    //Here we check if the device is charging
        UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true  //Here we disable the lock screen time out value
        self.chargingVar = "is charging. \u{1F603}" //Here we change the variable to "is charging" 
             chargingAlaer()    //If power is pluged in we send an Alert
      }else{
        self.chargingVar = "is not charging. \u{1F622} "  //Here we change the variable to "is not charging"  
             chargingAlaer()         //If power is not pluged we send an Alert
    }


}

func chargingAlaer(){
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Charging Status",
                                            message: "Your device \(chargingVar)",
        preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK",
                           style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,
                           handler: {(action) -> Void in
    })
    alertController.addAction(ok)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a notification on battery state change with `UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChange`, the code looking something like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    self,
    selector: #selector(batteryStateChanged),
    name: .UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChange,
    object: nil)
```

Of course, you need a method in ViewController (or wherever you want to get notification). In this example:

```
func batteryStateChanged(){
    // Your logic
}
```

Comment: I'll try this out, in the long run I am wanting it to play a sound whenever it gets unplugged.